# Flex Mobile on Android: captive runtime yes or no?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

I have to make the desicion if I pack my app with or without the captive runtime. Without it the app would only be 1 mb, but the user has to download some extra software and probably don't know why. With captive runtime the app would be 10 mb what could put people off downloading. Can anyone come up with better arguments for any of these options?

Comment: This is not a question that can concretely be answered, since you are asking for opinion.  As such, I voted to close.

Comment: I only want arguments/opinions, this could help others to make this decision.

Comment: Please read the FAQ for types of questions this site targets: http://stackoverflow.com/faq . To quote: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."

Comment: Ok you're right. Question can be closed. I don't know how reasonable this paragraph is though. Sometimes even in computer programming you can't act completely logical and have to discuss to take the lesser of two evil in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usability over "high" download volume. 10MB really isn't that much and if the mobile connection is too slow, users can always go back to a wireless connection to get your app.

I'd much rather wait (or connect to a different network) a couple of minutes than to hassle with installing extra software to run the app, not speaking about the extra time it would take me to install that software (which would most likely take longer than the time to download 10MB).